# Need suggesstion for IOS app review guideline for Paypal IOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

do we need to give any credential of Paypal account while submitting application to apple store? 
if yes, then Which kind of information and what information?

Is there any documentation for that from apple side?

i am dealing with Physical goods means to buy them i am using paypal IOS sdk.

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.